# copy from vim into stackoverflow for example

Tags: vim, ubuntu-12.04

I have being trying to get `crtl + V` to select all lines of text and then using `"+y` and `"*y` but that doesn't seem to work when I try to paste into the forum.

Additionally, I have been to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562350/copy-and-paste-from-external-source) and tried changing Vims /.vimrc with the un-named clipboard option but that hasn't worked either.

How can I copy from Vim into a forum post without doing `shift + crl + c` and then having to remove the line numbers?

Comment: I don't know which browse do u use. Firefox I have its all text. Chrome I have textAid installed. so that I can edit textarea with my gvim. also don't care about the paste problem... :)

Comment: @Kent I am using Firefox.

Comment: `ctrl+v` enables the block wise selection. Haven you mistaken it for `shift + v`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure you are using a proper Vim build. The default Vim on most (if not all) Linux distributions is a "tiny" build that lacks clipboard support among other interesting features. You can verify that by running this command in your terminal emulator:

   ```
   $ vim --version | grep clipboard
   ```

   A `+` in front of a feature means that it's built-in, a `-` means that the feature is missing.
2. If your Vim has no clipboard support, you should consider upgrading it to a proper build. On debian-based systems, this is typically done with this command:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
   ```

   At this point, you should be able to use `"+y` and experiment with `:h 'clipboard`.

However, this works only if your Vim runs locally. If you are using Vim on a remote machine, you can't have remote Vim talk to local clipboard unless you use the `-X` flag upon connection to enable "X11 forwarding" which comes with a variety of side effects and requirements.

Comment: I had everything except clipboard support.  Thanks.