# vim: access to clipboard / pasting text from external clipboard

Tags: vim

I've seen a guy (in a tutorial) pasting text, which he has copied (or yanked?) in a browser, in a file in vim. I was not able to reproduce this - I'm not very experienced in using vi or vim.

I can quote from this [site](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard):

> Vim has extended vi to allow use of the * register as a reference to
>   the system clipboard. So we can use normal mode commands like: "*dd or
>   1G"*yG to copy things into the * register and "*p to paste text from
>   it.

So my question (slightly [related is this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-to-paste-text-into-vim-command-line) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562350/copy-and-paste-from-external-source), which I don't quite understand) is: how can I get access to any clipboard using vim in Fedora/Gnome?

```
:"*p
```

did not work for me,

```
:*p
```

neither.

Thanks!

Comment: `"*p` is a normal mode command: you are not supposed to use it in command-line mode. Since the command you use isn't supposed to do what you expect it to do it's hard to say if the issue is on Vim's side or yours or if there's even an actual issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check whether your Vim has support for this: `:version` must include `+clipboard`.

On Linux, there's a distinction between the *primary selection* (register `*`) and the *system clipboard* (register `+`). See `:help quoteplus` for details. Best select / copy something and check the output of `:register *+` whether it's there.

Finally, the way to get and put things from / to the clipboard in Vim is through the register name. For *normal mode* commands, that means prefixing `"+` to the `p` (put) or `y` (yank) command, e.g. typing <kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>. There's also an Ex command for command-line mode (which you've attempted), but this takes the register as an argument (and without the `"`): `:put +`

Comment: aha, :version gives me -clipboard . I'll check how to get it.

Comment: You may only have the minimal Vim installed and need to get a `vim-full` or `vim-gnome` (or so) package installed.

Comment: I'm afraid, I can't find the right package. So far I did:

`[root@localhost ~]# yum list installed | grep vim
vim-common.x86_64           2:7.4.417-1.fc20        @updates                    
vim-enhanced.x86_64         2:7.4.417-1.fc20        @updates                    
vim-filesystem.x86_64       2:7.4.417-1.fc20        @updates                    
vim-minimal.x86_64          2:7.4.417-1.fc20        @updates`

`yum` does not know `vim-gnome`, `yum search vi\*` didn't yield a result - do I have to use an rpm package from elsewhere?

Comment: Try `vim-X11`, cp. http://superuser.com/questions/194747/how-to-install-vim-with-clipboard-support-on-fedora

Answer (score 1):

VIM 8.1.2269 with `+clipboard` & `+xterm_clipboard` enabled.

I do <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>